# How to add elements into matrix row wise, separated by space?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Consider a square matrix A of size N x N and an index (X, Y). Write a program to print the Quotient Q, when the sum
of diagonal elements of A is divided by the Single Digit Sum of A[X][Y]. Consider the diagonal which starts from
A[0][0]. The Single Digit Sum of a number is the sum of digits of A[X][Y] done repeatedly until a single digit is found.
Read the input from STDIN and print the output to STDOUT. Do not write arbitrary strings while reading the input or
while printing, as these contribute to the standard output.

Constraints:

```
 I) 1 < N <= 35

II) 0 <= X, Y < N
```

Input Format:

- First line of input contains N.
- Next N lines of input contain N integers each, separated by a single white space.
- Last line of input contains X and Y separated by a single white
  space.

Output Format:

- The output contains Q.

Sample Input1:

```
3
11 22 33
44 55 66
77 88 99
1 1
```

Sample Output1:

```
165
```

i just started tell me where I am getting wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class matrix {
    static BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static String[] a;
    static int[] a1;
    
    public static void stringar() throws IOException {
        
         a =bi.readLine().split(" ");
         a1=new int[a.length];
         for(int i1=0;i1<a.length;i1++) {
                a1[i1]=Integer.parseInt(a[i1]);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        int i = 0,j = 0,N,sum=0;
        N = bi.read();

        int[][] mat = new int[N][N];
 
            System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix") ;
            stringar();
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                if(k==N&&i==N) {
                    break;
                }
                if(j==N) {
                    k=0;
                    j=0;
                    i++;
                    stringar();
                    continue;
                }
                mat[i][j]=a1[k];
                j++;
                
            }
            
            System.out.println("The elements of the matrix") ;
            for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            { 
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                { 
                    System.out.print(mat[i][j]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println("");
        }

            for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            { 
                for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                { 
                if(i==j)    //this condition checks for diagonal
                {
                    sum = sum + mat[i][j];
                }
                }
        }

            System.out.print("SUM of DIAGONAL elements of the matrix = "+sum) ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: "Do not write arbitrary strings while reading the input or while printing, as these contribute to the standard output."!!!

Comment: Who prints the "prosa"? (Was it prefilled code?)

Comment: Consider defining a method `divide(matrix divisor)` which returns the result of dividing the matrix it's invoked on by the one specified in the argument. Then, in your `main()` method, instantiate two `matrix` objects and print the quotient. Also, per Java naming conventions, `matrix` as a class name should have a capital M.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
class DiagonalSumOfMatrix{
    static int N=0;enter code here
    static int[]arr()throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bi = newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[]strNums;
        strNums = bi.readLine().split(" ");
        int num[] = new int[strNums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strNums.length; i++) {
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
        }
        return num; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        N=sc.nextInt();
        int num[]=new int[N];
        int[][] mat = new int[N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num= arr();                                                                                         
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                mat[i][j]=num[j];
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) { 
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++) { 
                if(i==j) {
                    sum = sum + mat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answer can be more confusing and less inviting to apply, please support your answer with brief explanation of the approach and use code comments as well.